# shoping cart data display in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to display the order details form database. I store cart data into database using serialize method. When i want to display data i can not properly show it. only can print order object. And there give that a error.That is

> (1/1) FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach'
>   (T_ENDFOREACH) in 9ad30ab1db6ca668d8a75c428e65858dc800d045.php line 27
>   .

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1>User Profile</h1>
        <hr>
        <h2>My Oders</h2>
        @foreach($orders as $order)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @forecah($order->cart->items as $product)
                      <li class="list-group-item">
                        <span class="badge">{{$product['product_price']}} 
                      </span>
                        {{$product['item']['product_name']}} | 
                       {{$product['qty']}} Units
                      </li>
                      @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
             <strong>Total Price : {{$order->cart->totalPrice}}</strong>
            </div>          
        </div>
         @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your code:

```
@forecah($order->cart->items as $product)
```

Try to change into:

```
@foreach($order->cart->items as $product)e
```

Hope it works..as it does  not detect the foreach loop before.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong spelling of `forecah`. you should correct the spelling.
Look at the second `foreach` and change the spelling.
You can copy code below as i have changed the spelling.

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h1>User Profile</h1>
    <hr>
    <h2>My Oders</h2>
    @foreach($orders as $order)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($order->cart->items as $product)
                  <li class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="badge">{{$product['product_price']}} 
                  </span>
                    {{$product['item']['product_name']}} | 
                   {{$product['qty']}} Units
                  </li>
                  @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
         <strong>Total Price : {{$order->cart->totalPrice}}</strong>
        </div>          
    </div>
     @endforeach
</div>
```